# Why I'm getting column entries with empty values?

Tags: database, cassandra, command-line-interface

I'm using CassandraDB for saving Metrics data.

I created a columnfamily with name `metrics`:

```
CREATE TABLE metrics (
  mbean text,
  metricstime timestamp,
  ftpconnectionstate int,
  PRIMARY KEY (mbean, metricstime));
```

The resulting "table" in cqlsh looks like that:

```
 mbean     | metricstime              | ftpconnectionstate
-----------+--------------------------+--------------------
 FtpOnline | 2016-10-10 14:38:45+0000 |                  1
 FtpOnline | 2016-10-10 14:38:50+0000 |                  1
 FtpOnline | 2016-10-10 14:38:55+0000 |                  1
 FtpOnline | 2016-10-10 14:39:00+0000 |                  1
 FtpOnline | 2016-10-10 14:39:05+0000 |                  1
 FtpOnline | 2016-10-10 14:39:10+0000 |                  1
 FtpOnline | 2016-10-10 14:39:15+0000 |                  1
 FtpOnline | 2016-10-10 14:39:20+0000 |                  1
```

Under the hood cassandra saves the value like that:

```
RowKey: FtpOnline
=> (name=2016-10-10 14\:38\:45+0000:, value=, timestamp=1476110327630000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=2016-10-10 14\:38\:45+0000:ftpconnectionstate, value=00000001, timestamp=1476110327630000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=2016-10-10 14\:38\:50+0000:, value=, timestamp=1476110331832000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=2016-10-10 14\:38\:50+0000:ftpconnectionstate, value=00000001, timestamp=1476110331832000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=2016-10-10 14\:38\:55+0000:, value=, timestamp=1476110336830000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=2016-10-10 14\:38\:55+0000:ftpconnectionstate, value=00000001, timestamp=1476110336830000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=2016-10-10 14\:39\:00+0000:, value=, timestamp=1476110341831000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=2016-10-10 14\:39\:00+0000:ftpconnectionstate, value=00000001, timestamp=1476110341831000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=2016-10-10 14\:39\:05+0000:, value=, timestamp=1476110346832000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=2016-10-10 14\:39\:05+0000:ftpconnectionstate, value=00000001, timestamp=1476110346832000, ttl=604800)
```

Now you can see that there are column entries with empty values. 
My question is: Is there a possibility to get rid of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are referring to the value= on every other line.  They are there because the value is actually stored as the name of that field.  This is how Cassandra stores Clustering Keys.  Since the value is in the name, there is no point in including it in the "value" field as well.  Typically this view is distracted as it's not something that the user needs to worry about.